# Android contact picker: pick phone or email

Tags: android, email, android-contacts, phone-number, picker

Is it possible for the android contact picker to show a list of phone numbers & email address, and the user can select either a phone or an email.

I've tried the following Intents:

```
Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI // - selects the entire contact
Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI    // - select only phones
Intent.ACTION_PICK, Email.CONTENT_URI    // - select only emails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's already been answered : [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954413/android-contact-picker-get-name-number-email) 
but i will just post the code here

```
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    try {
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
                                                // column index of the contact ID
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                                                // column index of the contact name 
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        txtNombreContacto.setText(name);        //print data            
                                                // column index of the phone number
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        txtTelefono.setText(phone);         //print data
                    } 
                    pCur.close();
                                                // column index of the email   
        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(        
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",  
                new String[]{id}, null); 
            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                // This would allow you get several email addresses
                    // if the email addresses were stored in an array  
                String email = emailCur.getString(
                              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));                                         
                txtMailContacto.setText(email);         //print data
        } 
        emailCur.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What I was trying to do was configure the contact picker to present a UI that allows picking either an email or phone number. It seems this is not possible. I did use the code above and created a UI to display a list of emails and phones for the contact that was picked from the Android contact picker.